# List all sub-directories with a specific pattern in bash and execute a command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, regex, find

I have a directory like this:

```
.
./foo/.bar/bar/file.jpg
./foo/.bar/xyw/dummy.fil
./foo3/.bar/file.jpg
./foo3/.bar/bar/file.jpg
./fo/bar/file.jpg
```

I'm trying to list all subdirectories that contain the word `bar` (without including the `.bar`). And execute a command in those folders (a simple `ls` to start with).

I'm trying to use find but I can't figure out how to filter on `bar` without taking `.bar` :(

### edit

I have tested a few combination of `find`:

```
find . -d -name '*bar*' -exec {ls} 
find . -d | grep 'bar'
```

The problem is I don't know how to filter `.bar` and keep `bar`.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. First of all [it is not a good idea to parse the output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Second you may find interesting `find` (try `man find` for example) and its options `-name` (or `-path`), `-prune` (to exclude), `-type` and `-exec`... (and maybe `-maxdepth`). Try something and [edit] your question adding the point in which you find a problem...

Comment: I don't understand the problem. With the given example this too-simple command will work: `find . -type d -name bar`. Perhaps you should add more examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your first `find` command.

1. You need to exclude the `.bar` directories.  We can add a `-not` to our `find` to achieve this.
2. Your `ls` won't work like that.  `find` runs your command in the same directory you started in, so you need to give `ls` an argument of `{}` to pass through the directory that find is looking at.

This results in: `find . -type d -name '*bar*' -not -name '.bar*' -exec 'ls' '{}' ';'`

You also need to terminate the `-exec` for `find` with a `;` but the shell will interpret that so you have to put it in quotes to get it through to `find`.

I'm not sure whether you'd prefer to exclude `'.bar*'` or `'.bar'`, but I'm hoping you can customize that part of it.  From the Unix perspective it will work either way.  It is just up to your preference and use case.

Comment: (1) `-not` is not portable. The portable syntax for negation is `!`. (2) It's true one needs to quote (or escape) this `;`. Quoting `ls` or `{}` is absolutely unnecessary though. (3) Despite my nitpicking the answer is good. Upvoted.

Comment: Agreed on nits.  Quoting `ls` is certainly excessive, but it seems easier on the person just learning the shell to single quote all of the `exec` arguments and learn the nuances of double versus single quoting in a less confusing context.

Comment: Thank you chicks. With the example you gave, I now understand what I was doing wrong. I tried with regex, with grep etc but now it's easier to understand my mistakes.